# Как убрать белый экран при открытии свернутого приложения?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть простое приложение, которое являет собой webwidget. Проблема в том что когда я сворачиваю игру, то при повторном открытии я вижу только белый экран. Уже много всего перепробовал, но пока ничего не помогло. Подозреваю что решение кроется в методе onResume, но без понятия что туда добавить для фикса. При этом игра так же работает даже в свернутом режиме судя по звукам(что так же хотелось бы пофиксить) и при тапе на белом экране игра реагирует. [Видео демоснстрация бага](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4iIF7kdloU&feature=youtu.be).

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private WebView web;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.flappy);

    web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    web.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    web.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Dino/index.html");
  }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/flappy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась все-таки в самом веб виджете(при сворачивании проскакивает смена ориентации из-за чего канвас слетает). Понять это очень легко - меняете фон в вашем html документе, если фон поменялся - значит веб виджет на месте и соответственно проблема в позиционировании канваса или любого другого элемента, но лично у меня проблема была в изменении размеров канваса.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте убрать в манифесте:

> android:noHistory="true"

или поставить false. Если true, то к остановленной Activity вернуться будет нельзя. Возможно, именно в этом проблема.

И проверьте остальной код, нет ли где-нибудь асинхронных процессов. Бывает, что они дают такое зависание.

Comment: Добавлял как раз эту опцию как вариант фикса по совету из похожего вопроса, но не сработало. Забыл убрать. Но в целом ничего не дает. В самом приложении используется только requestAnimationFrame, но сомневаюсь что проблема именно в коде вебвиджета, хотя ещё потестирую.